# How do I put my state objects into a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to load these state objects into a 2d array. I need them in the following fashion:

```
[
  [
    "josie",
    "ally",
    "fred"
  ],
  [
    "edward",
    "ally",
    "fred",
    "goolly"
  ]
]
```

I need it this way because I need a way to reference the sublist relative to the name of the sublist.

```
 class App extends Component {

  state = {
    List: [
      {
        name: "josie", 
        sub: [
          "ally",
          "fred"
        ] 
      },
      {
        name: "edward", 
        sub: [
          "ally",
          "fred",
          "goolly"
        ] 
      }
    ]
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I apologize if this is too basic, but I am really beating my head on this.

Comment: Your first code block isn't valid JS.  Assuming they're strings, are you trying to make the first one turn into the second or the other way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of shortest ES6 versions to implement that will be the following:

```
state.List.forEach(listItem => finalArr.push([].concat([listItem.name], listItem.sub)));
```

Here we iterate over `List` array and push to `finalArr` a new array, which we generate by merging values of `name` and `sub` object properties into one new array. And finally we have an array of arrays (each sub array generated from separate items from `state.List`). Here is the working example:

```js
const state = {
    List: [
      {
        name: "josie", 
        sub: [
          "ally",
          "fred"
        ] 
      },
      {
        name: "edward", 
        sub: [
          "ally",
          "fred",
          "goolly"
        ] 
      }
    ]
}
const finalArr = [];
state.List.forEach(listItem => finalArr.push([].concat([listItem.name], listItem.sub)));
console.log(finalArr);
```